# import npm module using 'require' in Node.js

Tags: node.js, npm

I have a naive question regarding importing npm modules on Node.js server.

I have installed 'ml-random-forest' module via npm and have been trying to import the package.

I can import it via `import { RandomForestClassifier as RFClassifier } from 'ml-random-forest';` but I cannot import like `var RFClassifier = require('ml-random-forest');`

How can I import that package using 'require' ?

Comment: Please, write briefly about error you face while importing using require.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that when you call :

```
import {existingVariableFromTheLib as 
yourOwnNameForIt} from 'that_library'
```

You're actually importing an element of this library.

But when you're calling :

```
const anAlias = require('this_lib')
```

You're putting inside of the constant "anAlias" the totality of the library.

What you could try is then to call :

```
anAlias.existingVariableFromTheLib
```

Or, another way of dealing with this is to import using this way :

```
const {existingVariableFromTheLib} 
=require('lib')
//or : 
const anAlias = 
require('lib').existingVar
//maybe
const anAlias = 
require('lib').existingFunction()
```